# Bootstrap carousel not showing properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using this bootstrap carousel: https://codepen.io/kreigd/pen/ybYNoN

I did copy the files to my theme but it is still not showing properly and I don't receive any errors. Here is the HTML/CSS/Javascript of my code.

My jQuery is loaded before my bootstrap js so that is not the problem.

I can't find the answer anywhere so I would really appreciate the help!

U also can take a look at the website itself and inspect the code: `http://www.bureauvdo.jevdopilot.nl/over-ons/`

```js
$("#myCarousel").on("slide.bs.carousel", function(e) {
  var $e = $(e.relatedTarget);
  var idx = $e.index();
  var itemsPerSlide = 3;
  var totalItems = $(".carousel-item").length;

  if (idx >= totalItems - (itemsPerSlide - 1)) {
    var it = itemsPerSlide - (totalItems - idx);
    for (var i = 0; i < it; i++) {
      // append slides to end
      if (e.direction == "left") {
        $(".carousel-item")
          .eq(i)
          .appendTo(".carousel-inner");
      } else {
        $(".carousel-item")
          .eq(0)
          .appendTo($(this).find(".carousel-inner"));
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```css
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  /* show 3 items */
  .carousel-inner .active,
  .carousel-inner .active + .carousel-item,
  .carousel-inner .active + .carousel-item + .carousel-item {
    display: block;
  }

  .carousel-inner
  .carousel-item.active:not(.carousel-item-right):not(.carousel-item-left),
  .carousel-inner
  .carousel-item.active:not(.carousel-item-right):not(.carousel-item-left)
  + .carousel-item,
  .carousel-inner
  .carousel-item.active:not(.carousel-item-right):not(.carousel-item-left)
  + .carousel-item
  + .carousel-item {
    transition: none;
  }

  .carousel-inner .carousel-item-next,
  .carousel-inner .carousel-item-prev {
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }

  .carousel-inner
  .active.carousel-item
  + .carousel-item
  + .carousel-item
  + .carousel-item {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: -33.3333%;
    z-index: -1;
    display: block;
    visibility: visible;
  }

  /* left or forward direction */
  .active.carousel-item-left + .carousel-item-next.carousel-item-left,
  .carousel-item-next.carousel-item-left + .carousel-item,
  .carousel-item-next.carousel-item-left + .carousel-item + .carousel-item,
  .carousel-item-next.carousel-item-left
  + .carousel-item
  + .carousel-item
  + .carousel-item {
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    visibility: visible;
  }

  /* farthest right hidden item must be abso position for animations */
  .carousel-inner .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    display: block;
    visibility: visible;
  }

  /* right or prev direction */
  .active.carousel-item-right + .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right,
  .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right + .carousel-item,
  .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right + .carousel-item + .carousel-item,
  .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right
  + .carousel-item
  + .carousel-item
  + .carousel-item {
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
    visibility: visible;
    display: block;
    visibility: visible;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <h1 class="text-center mb-3">Bootstrap Multi-Card Carousel</h1>
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner row w-100 mx-auto">
      <div class="carousel-item col-md-4 active">
        <div class="card">
          <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/800x600/f44242/fff" alt="Card image cap">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title">Card 1</h4>
            <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item col-md-4">
        <div class="card">
          <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/800x600/418cf4/fff" alt="Card image cap">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title">Card 2</h4>
            <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item col-md-4">
        <div class="card">
          <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/800x600/3ed846/fff" alt="Card image cap">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title">Card 3</h4>
            <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item col-md-4">
        <div class="card">
          <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/800x600/42ebf4/fff" alt="Card image cap">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title">Card 4</h4>
            <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item col-md-4">
        <div class="card">
          <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/800x600/f49b41/fff" alt="Card image cap">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title">Card 5</h4>
            <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item col-md-4">
        <div class="card">
          <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/800x600/f4f141/fff" alt="Card image cap">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title">Card 6</h4>
            <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item col-md-4">
        <div class="card">
          <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/800x600/8e41f4/fff" alt="Card image cap">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title">Card 7</h4>
            <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to include in your HTML code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @JariRengeling if you are happy with the answer can you mark it as valid answer

Answer (score 0):

check below example

```js
$("#myCarousel").on("slide.bs.carousel", function(e) {
  var $e = $(e.relatedTarget);
  var idx = $e.index();
  var itemsPerSlide = 3;
  var totalItems = $(".carousel-item").length;

  if (idx >= totalItems - (itemsPerSlide - 1)) {
    var it = itemsPerSlide - (totalItems - idx);
    for (var i = 0; i < it; i++) {
      // append slides to end
      if (e.direction == "left") {
        $(".carousel-item")
          .eq(i)
          .appendTo(".carousel-inner");
      } else {
        $(".carousel-item")
          .eq(0)
          .appendTo($(this).find(".carousel-inner"));
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```css
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  /* show 3 items */
  .carousel-inner .active,
  .carousel-inner .active + .carousel-item,
  .carousel-inner .active + .carousel-item + .carousel-item {
    display: block;
  }

  .carousel-inner
  .carousel-item.active:not(.carousel-item-right):not(.carousel-item-left),
  .carousel-inner
  .carousel-item.active:not(.carousel-item-right):not(.carousel-item-left)
  + .carousel-item,
  .carousel-inner
  .carousel-item.active:not(.carousel-item-right):not(.carousel-item-left)
  + .carousel-item
  + .carousel-item {
    transition: none;
  }

  .carousel-inner .carousel-item-next,
  .carousel-inner .carousel-item-prev {
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }

  .carousel-inner
  .active.carousel-item
  + .carousel-item
  + .carousel-item
  + .carousel-item {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: -33.3333%;
    z-index: -1;
    display: block;
    visibility: visible;
  }

  /* left or forward direction */
  .active.carousel-item-left + .carousel-item-next.carousel-item-left,
  .carousel-item-next.carousel-item-left + .carousel-item,
  .carousel-item-next.carousel-item-left + .carousel-item + .carousel-item,
  .carousel-item-next.carousel-item-left
  + .carousel-item
  + .carousel-item
  + .carousel-item {
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    visibility: visible;
  }

  /* farthest right hidden item must be abso position for animations */
  .carousel-inner .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    display: block;
    visibility: visible;
  }

  /* right or prev direction */
  .active.carousel-item-right + .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right,
  .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right + .carousel-item,
  .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right + .carousel-item + .carousel-item,
  .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right
  + .carousel-item
  + .carousel-item
  + .carousel-item {
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
    visibility: visible;
    display: block;
    visibility: visible;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <h1 class="text-center mb-3">Bootstrap Multi-Card Carousel</h1>
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner row w-100 mx-auto">
      <div class="carousel-item col-md-4 active">
        <div class="card">
          <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/800x600/f44242/fff" alt="Card image cap">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title">Card 1</h4>
            <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item col-md-4">
        <div class="card">
          <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/800x600/418cf4/fff" alt="Card image cap">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title">Card 2</h4>
            <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item col-md-4">
        <div class="card">
          <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/800x600/3ed846/fff" alt="Card image cap">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title">Card 3</h4>
            <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item col-md-4">
        <div class="card">
          <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/800x600/42ebf4/fff" alt="Card image cap">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title">Card 4</h4>
            <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item col-md-4">
        <div class="card">
          <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/800x600/f49b41/fff" alt="Card image cap">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title">Card 5</h4>
            <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item col-md-4">
        <div class="card">
          <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/800x600/f4f141/fff" alt="Card image cap">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title">Card 6</h4>
            <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item col-md-4">
        <div class="card">
          <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/800x600/8e41f4/fff" alt="Card image cap">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title">Card 7</h4>
            <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why is this working and why is it not working on my website? Even if i paste this code.

Comment: it is workable solution, you should at least upvote, there should be some minor mistake from your side, please cross verify it